# How to get simple class name from a qualified class name using oracle/postgres query?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, split

I have fully qualified class names like below. 
'com.test.Person', 'com.test.fruit.Apple', 'com.test.color.Red'

I need to get the simple class names Person,Apple,Red as result from these strings using oracle query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use substr. And instr for find last '.'

```sql
with test (col)
     as (select 'com.test.Person' from DUAL
         union all
         select 'com.test.fruit.Apple' from DUAL
         union all
         select 'com.test.color.Red' from DUAL)
select col, SUBSTR (col, INSTR (col, '.', -1) + 1) class
  from test
```

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'com.test.Person'       from dual union all
  3     select 'com.test.fruit.Apple'  from dual union all
  4     select 'com.test.color.Red'    from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7         regexp_substr(col, '\w+$') result
  8  from test;

COL                  RESULT
-------------------- --------------------
com.test.Person      Person
com.test.fruit.Apple Apple
com.test.color.Red   Red

SQL>
```

Comment: How it'll be for postgres?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't use Postgres.

Comment: Thanks Little foot for reply.

Comment: No problem; sorry I couldn't help.